# Where does VueJS store the cached component when using keep-alive

Tags: vue.js, keep-alive

I am looking for information on where Vue stores the cached component data when a component is wrapped in the keep-alive component. I looked at the local storage, cache storage, and session storage but I don't see anything obvious. I suspect that the cache is stored in the DOM but I was hoping that someone might know for sure or offer some clarification.

The issue I am having is that I have some Vue components that I am wrapping as web components using https://github.com/vuejs/vue-web-component-wrapper. This library is responsible for adding the keep-alive to my vue components. These components are then used inside other front end frameworks. The keep alive doesn't work as expected in this scenario, if I navigate away from the component and return the component is not restored to it's previous state. What I am expecting to happen is that navigation away from the component and returning restores the component to it's previous state as described in https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html

Comment: To clarify you are creating Vue Components which internally use `keep-alive` then you use the library you linked to wrap them and use them in some other non-Vue project, correct? Please edit your question to include what is happening and what you are expecting.

Comment: More or less except that the vue components don't use keep-alive internally, that's a function of the linked library. I made some edits to my question.

Comment: You need to be sure that the keep-alive component stays and is not removed, if you have a v-if for example in the parent component, it will detroy the keep-alive and everything inside.

Comment: That is correct and there aren't any v-ifs on the keep alive component but that sounds like what I'm experiencing. If the component gets used inside say Angular, I'm assuming that the component is destroyed and the state is lost if a user navigates away. To confirm that this is the case, I am trying to figure out where Vue keeps the cached state of the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging around - in the implementation of keep-alive ([Here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/components/keep-alive.js#L90)).
You can see that the cache is stored locally on the component level, meaning that if the `<keep-alive>` is removed from the DOM it will lose its stored cache.

In theory, if you need it another way you may extend the component - create a prop like `cacheName` that you pass down to it. Have on mounted check if there is anything in localStorage for that prop to supplement it. Then add a watcher (deep) to watch for changes to the cache and store it in LocalStorage with the key coming for `cacheName`.

Some rough code of how the component may look - [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/lightning00blade/4ymwt1xs/). Keep in mind that it may not be possible to get the object from Vue this way so you may need to copy the whole thing then add the code on top of it.